# WPF: Change Button Text when SHIFT is pressed

Tags: c#, wpf, keypress

I would like to change the text (Content property) of a button when the SHIFT key is pressed. In that cases the button shall execute a different command. That is a common UI behaviour e. g. in Photoshop.

Any idea how to do this.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Add the `KeyDown` or `PreviewKeyDown` event to your Button element.

```
<Button Width="300" Height="50" Name="btnFunction" KeyDown="btnFunctionKeyDown" Content="Function1"/>
```

And the C# Code:

```
private void btnFunctionKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.LeftShift || e.Key == Key.RightShift)
    {
        btnFunction.Content = "Function2";
    }
}
```

Have a look on this Article for more information:

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.keyboard.keydown?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Many thanks for the swift reply - is that solution also working of the Button does not have focus?

Comment: If it should work if the Button does not have focus, you have to add the PreviewKeyDown event to the Window or the Grid itself. Make sure you add e.Handled = true if you you use the PreviewKeyDown event.

Comment: This will only work if the button in question has the focus. If something else has the focus and the user presses the shift button and then clicks the UI button it won' work. Therefore it doesn't solve the question the OP asked.

Comment: This turns out to be a little more complicated than assumed. First I need to reset the button text when shift is released - okay I can do that but using KeyUp events. 
But if I add the handler to the window, the shift key does not longer work in my TextBoxes in the case window...

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution (event is handled at the Window) - many thanks for your input - if there is a better solution kindly comment...

```
internal void HandlePreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    IInputElement focusedControl = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(_window);
    if (( (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Shift) == ModifierKeys.Shift) && !(focusedControl?.GetType() == typeof(TextBox)))
    {
       // set button text
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}

internal void HandlePreviewKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    IInputElement focusedControl = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(_window);
    if ( (e.Key == Key.LeftShift) || (e.Key == Key.RightShift) && !(focusedControl?.GetType() == typeof(TextBox)))
    {
         // re-set button text
         e.Handled = true;
    }  
}
```